# Arduino POST vs GET request

Tags: post, get, arduino, google-fusion-tables

I have a bunch of temperature data my Arduino monitors that I want to put into a Google Fusion table.  Fusion tables require OAuth for record inserts which the Arduino can't handle (I don't think), I want to create a little app Google's App Engine that will receive the data from the Arduino, then this app will authenticate with the Fusion table and insert a record.  Each record would have about 65 fields.  I don't know how to do the app on Google App Engine yet, but I'll figure that our separately.  What I'd like to know is the pros and cons of sending the data to the app using a GET request or a POST request from my Arduino.  For this scenario, is one a better choice then the other?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an HTTP POST request if you are wanting to send data from the Arduino.

The difference between the two is that GET is for requesting data **from** the server, while POST is for sending data **to** the server.

Here is a link for information about HTTP Message Types:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4

Now for the Arduino code, you need to do the following to send the POST request using the [**GSM Shield**](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield).

```
//First, establish a connection to the cell tower via GSM
String PIN = "123456";  //The PIN of your SIM card
gsmAccess.begin(PIN);

//Next, connect to your service provider's GPRS network (internet access)
String GPRS_APN = "The APN of your provider";
String GPRS_LOGIN = "Your login name";
String GPRS_PASSWORD = "Your password";
gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD);

//Now you need to connect a client to your GAE web server on port 80
client.connect("ServerName", 80);

//Now send the properly-formed HTTP POST request
String message = "The message body of the request, the data you want to send";
client.print("POST ");
client.print("/yourPathToDesiredPage");
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.print("Host: ");
client.println("ServerName");
client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(message.length());
client.println();
client.println(message);
client.endWrite();
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please accept/upvote it? If not, could you elaborate on how else I could help?